# Combine 2 if conditions in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a summation based on an if condition like the following code, I need to add one more condition before start to SUM(), 
ex:

```
process_status > 0 and publish is true \\to return 1
```

`

Code:

```
SELECT 
       sum(if(process_status > 0, 1, 0)) resource_completed,
       sum(if(process_status = 2, 1, 0)) resource_passed,
       sum(if(process_status = 3, 1, 0)) resource_failed
```

what's the correct way to combine multiple if conditions in select?

Comment: Much easier to understand using SUM(CASE...( in my view).

Comment: @P.Salmon please post a sample using CASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql Boolean expressions are evaluated as `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`, so you can write the condition like:

```
sum(process_status > 0 and publish)
```

and you can simplify your existing code to:

```
SELECT 
       sum(process_status > 0) resource_completed,
       sum(process_status = 2) resource_passed,
       sum(process_status = 3) resource_failed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use more condition as below-

```
SELECT stats.reference_id AS resource_id,
count(*) resource_started,
sum(if(process_status > 0 AND publish is true, 1, 0)) resource_completed
```

Answer (score 1):

Much easier to understand using SUM(CASE...( in my view)

```
select 
 sum(case when process_status > 0 and publish is true then 1 else 0 end)
```